# Binding root object and child collection to GridView / RadGridView MVVM

Tags: wpf, gridview, telerik, telerik-grid, radgridview

I have an object with a child collection of objects that represent attributes. I want to display this in a GridView in a denormalized format, as below:

```
Item tshirt = new Item("My Airwolf T-Shirt");
tshirt.Attributes.Add("Color", "Blue");
tshirt.Attributes.Add("Size", "M");
tshirt.Attributes.Add("Condition", "Tatty");
```

I want this to appear in the GridView in this manner:

[image: The grid output I need]

It must adhere to the following rules:

- The attributes will be dynamic, 0 to many.
- Each object in the collection will have the same attributes (i.e. in this case they will all have Color/Size/Condition), although the attributes in the collection as a whole may change dynamically.
- I'm using MVVM and databinding, but happy to create columns in the code behind.

Comment: ..and your question is ?

Answer (score 0):

I've made some progress with this...

It seems a solution is to use an IValueProvider. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993932/bind-gridview-with-dictionary-in-wpf-c-sharp) has a very thorough answer for a similar situation.